# Moving and zooming in and out problems

Tags: objects

Hey so I have a problem where at first I could move around my mesh easily and then suddenly it clips to max zooming or something and it becomes very hard to move around and control zooming in and out on mesh.

Comment: Hello :). This happens because your viewport is in perspective view. You can switch into orthographic view (Num 5) or use dolly zoom (Ctrl + Mousewheel drag).

Comment: Thanks! Now I can continue my progress :D